# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1' - Azure ServiceBus exception

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

While inserting message in ServiceBus Queue it is getting exception as below

```
Message:**Cannot access a disposed object**.
Object name: **'FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1'**.

Exception type  **System.ObjectDisposedException**
```

It is not happening for all the messages but happening for few messages

A CosmosDB Trigger Azure function which is inserting messages in Queue of ServiceBus
Code Snippet

```
public void ServiceBusQueueConnection()
    {
        try
        {               
            if (serviceBusConnectionString.Contains())
            {
                queueClient = new QueueClient(new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder());
            }
            else
            {
                queueClient = new QueueClient();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's likely something in the code but how to know if the code is not shared? 

Comment: can u check now and if u can able to help why this is getting error put

Comment: Where's `queueClient` coming from? Mate, if you want help you got to provide details. There's no IP in that code, you can share it 

Comment: added here as above please check

Comment: Any specific reason why you're not using an outgoing Service Bus binding and rather create a queue client yourself? It's also very inefficient as you're creating the connection each time and it's an expensive operation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
It would be helpful if you can share the correct approach so that I can look into and change as you have advised
Right now Could you please tell why so many messages are failing every day - Its real issue for me to solve..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output